# pagination - virtual addresses, physical addresses, mapping - considerations

Tags: memory, x86, paging, memory-address, cpu-architecture

> Pagination in some processor make it possible to map virtual address
>   (A2345678) to physical address (823C5678). However, it is not possible
>   to map virtual address (345678) to (2ABC678). **What can we conclude
>   about size of frame, page, size of virtual memory, size of physical
>   memory**.

What I think about it:
(A2345678) -> (823C5678)
So, size offset is most 19 bits. We know that size of page (and frame) has size at most 2<sup>19</sup>, [like in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849411/size-of-page-of-memory-reasoning-using-offset?).

When it comes to size of virtual memory, and physical memory - I can conclude  nothing.

Similary, I don't know what tell me information about non-possibility mapping address.

Can you try to explain it me ?

Comment: Where did you get this question?  I don't see any obvious conclusions either, other than about page size like [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849411/size-of-page-of-memory-reasoning-using-offset?).  I edited your question to link to it for context, so people know they don't need to explain that part in more detail.  (or can find out what method you used if they didn't know themselves).

Comment: Simply, I have a problem with this issues, could you help me ? Question is: What can we conclude from information in my post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do see something we can conclude after all:

If a mapping to physical address `0x823C5678` is possible, physical memory is at least that large.  (Assuming there aren't any holes in physical address space; not a good assumption on real hardware, but whatever.  We can tell that physical address space is at least that big, even if it doesn't all map to DRAM or MMIO).

Similarly, the valid virtual address `0xA2345678` gives us a lower bound on the virtual address size.  Presumably all the virtual address bits can be `1`, so the highest possible virtual address is at least `0xFFFFFFFF`.  i.e. virtual addresses are at least 32 bits, but could be any larger size.

This reasoning applies to physical address space, but not the size of physical memory.  (e.g. in a computer with 19GiB of RAM, the highest valid physical address isn't 2<sup>n</sup>-1.)

---

The fact that you can't map 0x345678 to 0x2ABC678 does tell us that the page size is greater than 2<sup>12</sup>.  The physical address is below the address that was mappable, so we can rule out that possible reason for the mapping being impossible.  I think too high and misaligned are the only possible reasons for a mapping not being possible.

(0xc = 0b1100, while 0x5 is 0b0101, so the common bits are only 0x678.)

---

We can assume that physical memory is a whole number of pages, so we can round up the lowest possible end of physical memory to the next multiple of 2<sup>13</sup>.

Comment: So address space of virtual memory is at least 2^{32}. What about physical space address ?  Also 2^{32} ?  What reasons did you rule out Too high addresss?

Comment: @HaskellFun: `0x823C5678` has its high bit set, so yes I think we can assume physical addresses have at least 32 bits.  We can rule out `0x2ABC678` because it's less than `0x823C5678`, like I said in my answer.

Comment: Moreover, size of frame is equal to size of page ? The last section is not clear for me - address space of physical (and here also virtual) is 32 bits. However what do you mean when it comes to 2^{13} ?

Comment: What does "frame" mean in this context?  I assume it's nothing to do with "stack frames", but IDK what it means.

Comment: @HaskellFun: We know that `0x823C5678` is a valid physical address, but it's not the end of a page.  The lower bound for the highest physical address is that with the low 13 bits set to 1, because we know the minimum page size is 2^13.

Comment: Firstly: From what you know that minimal size of page is 2^13 ? I mean how do you conclude it from impossibility of mapping ?

Comment: If the page size was 2^12 or smaller, the mapping would be possible.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It fairly obvious :)   From what you know that `0x823C5678` is not end of a page ?

Comment: If this isn't clear by now, ask your professor to help you make sure you understand everything.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it again and I understand why it is not end of page. End of Page may be addresss `0x823C5678` but with `1` as 13 last bits. However - how it is possible to conclude about size of physical memory ?